MSVC warning C26483 on every vector initialization of BetterEnums
I am using the BetterEnums library for enum reflection.  Without going into the details of the library's internal implementation, it is basically a class wrapping a regular enum, declared using macro and template magic.
Whenever I run MSVC's built-in Code Analysis, every place that declares and list-initializes a vector of such objects has an associated
Warning C26483: Value 1 is outside the bounds (0, 0) of variable 'allotemp.12'. Only index into arrays using constant expressions that are within bounds of the array (bounds.2).  (And then another one for Value 2 and however many items exist in the list-initialization.)
Something as simple as the following can trigger the warning:
BETTER_ENUM( MyEnum, int8_t,
    A,
    B,
    C
)

std::vector<MyEnum> myList = { MyEnum::A, MyEnum::B };

I'm used to getting some false warnings with this tool, and have learned with time which ones to ignore and which ones to listen to.  This one, however, I simply don't understand. Where is the indexing happening?
My setup:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.26
Toolset v142
Compiling for c++ 17

Edit: It also should be noted that I don't get these warnings anywhere else I use the enums, whether as a type or as direct initialization.  Only when list-initializing vectors.
Edit2: After dumping the preprocessor to file and aggressively pruning, I've reproduced it with the following class:
class  MyEnum
{
public:
    enum _enumerated : int8_t
    {
        A,
        B,
        C
    };
    constexpr MyEnum( _enumerated value ) : _value( value ) {}
    int8_t _value;
public:
    MyEnum() = default;
};

std::vector<MyEnum> myList = { MyEnum::A, MyEnum::B }; 


Can you show the code after expansion of BETTER_ENUM? My guess would be it's something in there.

@ChrisMM: The expansion is the essentially that whole library, so best I can do is a link to the github: https://github.com/aantron/better-enums/blob/520d8ee39037c9c94aa6e708a4fd6c0fa313ae80/enum.h#L1193

So a thousand lines of macros, and the compiler is confused. So am I.

With latest Visual Studio 2022, hovering over a macro let you expand it in the IDE for introspection, even in a step-by-step procedure. Should be instructive for that case.

Update to my previous comment: I tried to expand the macro in Visual Studio, but BETTER_ENUM seems to be too complex for the IDE and crashes the inline expansion engine!

Did you try to compile with compiler flag /Zc:preprocessor?

@prapin: I dumped the preprocessor to file and heavily pruned the output.  Edited the question to include what's left
